# How to DRYly render code snippets within a style guide

Tags: css, documentation, pug

I'm building a simple, static style guide. It includes only static front-end assets – CSS, JS, fonts, and images which will be included in client apps via bower. My development stack, however, is a bit more sophisticated. I'm using gulp to wire up jade, sass, coffeescript etc. Everything is working great.

In the guide, I would like to have a preview of the source code so that you can conveniently copy the markup for a widget and paste it directly into your project. You can see this, for example, in the docs for Foundation. I would like to do something similar in my styleguide.

**Now my question...**

Of course, I could just duplicate the markup (once to render the content and a second time in `pre` tags to render the code snippet). But that's obviously bad because then I run the risk of failing to keep them in sync, thus defeating the entire purpose of displaying a code snippet.

Ideally, I want to *type the markup once* and have it render both the content and the code snippet. In a previous project, I was able to achieve this by writing a custom HAML filter. How can I do this with Jade?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple solutions:

- [render-code](https://github.com/octopress/render-code) - for file based code snippets in the same repository
- [jekyll-github-sample](https://github.com/bwillis/jekyll-github-sample) - for code snippets from any GitHub repo